# What does the 'ar' parameter in arima.sim represent?

Tags: r, time-series, arima, autocorrelation

I want to generate a time series that follows an AR(1) process and thus has a certain overall level of autocorrelation.

I'm using the `arima.sim` function (which is implemented as standard in R).

I thought that for example the following command:

```
arima.sim(model=list(Ar=-0.5),n=400)
```

would generate a time series of length 400 and an autocorrelation of -0.5.
However, I've noticed that the values you can give to the `Ar` parameter are not limited to [-1; 1]. For example, you could input `10 000`.

Can anyone explain to me what the `Ar` parameter actually represents? Because it apparently is not a correlation coefficient.

After reading on the internet it seems to me that there's not a lot of information there for people who want to simulate time series data using a model as opposed to people who want to fit data to a model.

Answer (score 4):

The AR parameter is an auto*regression* parameter, which can certainly be outside the unit interval (yielding rather nonstationary time series).

If you write `ar=-0.5` instead of `Ar=-0.5` (R is case sensitive!), you will likely get closer to what you are looking for. Try this a couple of times (to account for randomness):

```
print(acf(arima.sim(model=list(ar=-0.5),n=400)))
```

Comment: You probably did not mean to have `Ar` but rather `ar` in the last line.

Comment: @RichardHardy: duh! Thank you! Wrong copy&paste from my Notepad.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it should be `ar`, not `Ar`. I don't think the values you supplied to `Ar` are doing anything. It's probably just generating a white noise process.

To answer your question, `arima.sim` allows you to simulate from an ARMA model, and the inputs are regression coefficients (using `ar` and `ma`) corresponding to the model here

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive%E2%80%93moving-average_model#ARMA_model

You will get an error if the model you specified is not stationary. All of this information is in the help file (type `help(arima.sim)`).

Answer (score -2):

**Generate The Two Time Series Length 999**
Fixed random seeds

```
set.seed(20140625)
```

Define length of simulation

```
> N <- 999
```

Simulate normal random walk

```
> x <- cumsum(rnorm(N))
```

Set an initial parameter

```
> gamma <- 0.7
```

Get cointegrating series

```
> y <- gamma * x + rnorm(N)
```

plot the two series

```
> plot(x, type='l') 
> lines(y,col="green")
> summary(ur.df(x,type="none"))

###############################################
# Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test Unit Root Test # 
###############################################

Test regression none


Call:
lm(formula = z.diff ~ z.lag.1 - 1 + z.diff.lag)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max
-2.9293 -0.6857 -0.0430  0.6568  3.0650

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
z.lag.1    -0.002151   0.002995  -0.718
z.diff.lag  0.015978   0.031770   0.503
           Pr(>|t|)
z.lag.1       0.473
z.diff.lag    0.615

Residual standard error: 0.9896 on 995 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.0007246, Adjusted R-squared:  -0.001284
F-statistic: 0.3608 on 2 and 995 DF,  p-value: 0.6972


Value of test-statistic is: -0.7182

Critical values for test statistics:
      1pct  5pct 10pct
tau1 -2.58 -1.95 -1.62
```

Comment: It's not clear to me how this addresses the question, which is "*Can anyone explain to me what the Ar parameter actually represents?*". I understand this may not have been clear from the title, so I have now edited it to reflect that.